# Analytics chart data change should remember the state if moving average was selected

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, analytics

Analytics chart data change should remember the state if moving average was selected.

Repro:

1. Open [se-site]/admin/analytics page.
2. Check the moving average checkbox.
3. Change the type of chart in the dropdown on the left.
4. See the moving average checkbox is no longer checked.

Apparently others wiser than I have indicated that it remembers by chart the last selection for this checkbox. I think that is counter-intuitive personally, and would rather the selection be all-or-none.

So apparently the FR has become: Store the state of the checkbox as a page-global variable (or at least chart-global, since there are two charts on the page) instead of a by-selection variable.